# Seven inch tablet layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, screen-density

I am developing an app with multiple screen support. I used layout-sw720dp folder for all 10 inch tablets and layout folder for all smartphones and 7 inch tablets.
I tested my app in Lanix Ilium Pad T7 http://phoneradar.com/gadgets/phones/lanix/ilium-pad-t7/ and it didn't take layouts from layout folder. I tried adding a layout-sw600dp and layout-sw600dp-hdpi folders but this device is still taking layouts from layout-sw720dp.

What I have to do to take layouts from another folder different to layout-sw720dp?

Answer (score 0):

Resources should be look like this. But if it not working for you, try test on other device.You can use very usefull tool like [this (Genymotion)](https://www.genymotion.com/) for non commercial use is  the best,in my opinion.

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For phones
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets
```

Also you can always simply select the resource to use in code

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
        @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate();

            Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
            if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) {
                setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_tablet);
            } else {
                setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to select resource in code, but the attribute smallestScreenWithDp returns 720. Is this normal?